# How has chalk.green.bold("Some Text") and chalk.bold.green("Some Text") been coded in the background in the npm package chalk

Tags: node.js, npm, design-patterns, chalk

I was recently using the [chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk) package while learning node. I tried using both `chalk.green.bold()` as well as `chalk.bold.green()` and got the same result. I like how it has been implemented where green is being used as both an object as well as a method. So to simplify my question how can you have a variable named say var and have the same output for

```js
    var.x.y.z()
    var.y.x.z()
    var.z.x.y()
    ...
```

all of these without explicitly defining functionality for them all? What design pattern is used(if any is used in this case)?